# Someone changed a program's name on my computer and now the program doesn't work. I would like to know how to undo this

Tags: windows-7, windows

Someone changed the name of Windows Media player on my computer by adding     the word 'configuration' and now it won't play. How do I undo this?

Comment: More details please about what was changed and where.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you think happened is what actually happened. There are lots of configuration files on your computer, including ones for Windows Media Player. So, how you are trying to open WMP and what makes you say a different thing is there?

Answer (score 1):

Press the windows key +r (this opens the 'run' command) 
Type 'appwiz.cpl' (without the quotes and press enter) ==> this will open the application wizard. Look for the program that 's not working correctly and click once on it. Normally, you should have the option to' repair' the problem. Try repairing it and see if it works properly afterwards.